# If two columns LaTeX

Tags: conditionals, two-column

I am writing a paper in LaTeX. I will need both the one-column and two-column versions of the paper. For this, the figure sizes/configurations need to be different in the two documents. I am looking for a command like `\iftwocolumn`! Do you know if it exists and if not how can I define and use it?

I would need something like:

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\iftwocolumn\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{FiguresDouble/figure.eps}
\else\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{FiguresSingle/figure.eps}
\fi
```

Answer (score 6):

`\linewidth` or `\columnwidth` should work, since a non-`twocolumn` document technically consists of a single column (of width `\columnwidth`).

However, if you're using the traditional `twocolumn` mode of (say) [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls), the condition `\if@twocolumn` is available for testing/branching.

Here's a short example showing the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makeatletter%
\if@twocolumn%
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
\else% \@twocolumnfalse
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}%
\fi
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Note that you require the use of a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair, since the command definition of the conditional contains `@`. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)

Comment: It looks like that \if@twocolumn works in the opposite way

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I made a conditional to do different things with one or two columns:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{article}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\if@twocolumn
\newcommand{\whencolumns}[2]{
#2
}
\else
\newcommand{\whencolumns}[2]{
#1
}
\fi
\makeatother

\whencolumns{One Column}{Two Columns}
\end{document}
```

When this is defined, you can do the original question like:

```
\whencolumns{
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{FiguresSingle/figure.eps}
}{
 \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{FiguresDouble/figure.eps}
}
```

This method does assume that the entire document is one or two columns and isn't switching.

Comment: Yes, the first block of code in the post is compilable.  I even use the \whencolumns in https://github.com/jrincayc/rationality-ai-zombies if you want to see it in use.