# Test if revtex is in reprint or in preprint mode

Tags: revtex

I am writing a revtex document that requires some equations to be typeset differently depending on whether I am in one-column `preprint` or in two-column `reprint` mode. Is there a way to specify separate equations depending on the mode?

This is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107830/if-two-columns-latex), but the solution proposed there doesn't seem to work with revtex:

```
\documentclass[aip,jcp,reprint,citeautoscript,longbibliography]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\if@twocolumn
\newcommand{\whencolumns}[2]{
#2
}
\else
\newcommand{\whencolumns}[2]{
#1
}
\fi
\makeatother

\whencolumns{One Column}{Two Columns}
\end{document}
```

This generates the text "One Column" both in `reprint` and in `preprint` mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class has

```
\DeclareOption{preprint}{%
 \@booleantrue\preprintsty@sw
 \ExecuteOptions{12pt}%
}
\DeclareOption{reprint}{%
 \@booleanfalse\preprintsty@sw
 \@booleantrue\twocolumn@sw
 \ExecuteOptions{10pt}%
}
```

So you can do

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\whencolumns}[2]{\preprintsty@sw{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[% Try both options
  preprint,
  %reprint,
]{revtex4-1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\whencolumns}[2]{\preprintsty@sw{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\whencolumns{Preprint}{Reprint}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I learned from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110292/testing-for-a-documentclass-option) it is quite easy to test if a class option is set:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4-1}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifpreprintoption
\@ifclasswith{revtex4-1}{preprint}{\preprintoptiontrue}{\preprintoptionfalse}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\ifpreprint}[2]{\ifpreprintoption #1\else #2\fi}

\begin{document}

\ifpreprint{Preprint}{Reprint}

\end{document}
```

prints "Preprint" if the preprint option is set, and "Reprint" otherwise.